# How can I assert query while ignoring difference in time produced by LocalDateTime.now()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have issues asserting time produced by LocalDateTime.now() methods, I want to assert whole query while ignoring time it produces. **Here is the code:**

```
 @Test
public void getLastDrawResult_lotteryIdPresent() {
    Optional<Long> lotteryId = Optional.of(3L);
    Optional<String> name = Optional.empty();
    Optional<String> byName = Optional.empty();
    Optional<String> byDate = Optional.empty();
    Optional<Boolean> jackpotOnly = Optional.empty();

    String query = QUERY_MAIN_BLOCK.replace("/*statement0*/", LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(buyingLock).toString()) + CONDITION_SEARCH_BY_LAST_DRAW_RESULT;
    String updatedQuery = query.replace("/*statement1*/", " WHERE d.lottery_info_id = 3") + " AND d.lottery_info_id = 3";

    DrawResultDto drawResultDto = DrawResultDto.builder().id(3L).build();
    List<DrawResultDto> expectedDrawResultDto = singletonList(drawResultDto);

    when(jdbcTemplate.query(updatedQuery, drawResultDtoQueryBuilder.queryMapper)).thenReturn(expectedDrawResultDto);
    List<DrawResultDto> actualDrawResultDto = drawResultDtoQueryBuilder.getLastDrawResult(lotteryId, name, byName, byDate, jackpotOnly);

    verify(jdbcTemplate).query(updatedQuery, drawResultDtoQueryBuilder.queryMapper);
    assertEquals(expectedDrawResultDto, actualDrawResultDto);
```

Here is the comparison Failure details, so you can have more idea what I need to ignore: [Comparison Failure Window Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJgFG.png)

**Here is the method I'm testing:**

```
public List<DrawResultDto> getLastDrawResult(Optional<Long> lotteryId, Optional<String> name, Optional<String> byName, Optional<String> byDate, Optional<Boolean> jackpotOnly) {
    String query = QUERY_MAIN_BLOCK.replace("/*statement0*/", LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(buyingLock).toString()) +
            CONDITION_SEARCH_BY_LAST_DRAW_RESULT;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (lotteryId.isPresent()) {
        builder.append(query.replace("/*statement1*/", " WHERE d.lottery_info_id = " + lotteryId.get()))
                .append(String.format(" AND d.lottery_info_id = %d", lotteryId.get()));
    } else {
        builder.append(query);
        name.ifPresent(nameValue -> builder.append(" AND lower(li.name) LIKE '%").append(SqlUtils.escapeLike(nameValue).toLowerCase()).append("%' "));
        jackpotOnly.ifPresent(jackpotOnlyValue -> {
            if (jackpotOnlyValue) {
                builder.append(" AND ").append(CONDITION_SEARCH_BY_JACKPOT_WIN);
            }
        });
        byName.ifPresent(s -> builder.append(" ORDER BY li.name ").append(SqlUtils.escapeLike(s)));
        byDate.ifPresent(s -> builder.append(" ORDER BY nfd.nearestDrawDate ").append(SqlUtils.escapeLike(s)));
        if (!byName.isPresent() && !byDate.isPresent()){
            builder.append(" ORDER BY li.name desc ");
        }
    }
    return jdbcTemplate.query(builder.toString(), queryMapper);
}
```

I tried to do matches() from Mockito, no luck. I can't seem to get the regex working. Like Match everything BUT the following Regex: `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})` . Which selects the part which I need to ignore.

Comment: It would be best that I don't do any changes to the class/method I'm testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best-practices here would involve you injecting a [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html), which will give you access to any objects (including LocalDateTime) you need via an override of the `now` method.

```
public List<DrawResultDto> getLastDrawResult(
    Optional<Long> lotteryId,
    Optional<String> name,
    Optional<String> byName,
    Optional<String> byDate,
    Optional<Boolean> jackpotOnly,
    Clock clock) {
  LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
  /* ... */
}
```

As in [Ash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42699773/1426891), you could make a method overload with your current signature that creates a new SystemClock, and then test the method that accepts the clock.

```
/** Your original method signature. No changes to any calling code. */
public List<DrawResultDto> getLastDrawResult(
    Optional<Long> lotteryId,
    Optional<String> name,
    Optional<String> byName,
    Optional<String> byDate,
    Optional<Boolean> jackpotOnly) {
  return getLastDrawResult(lotteryId, name, byName, byDate, jackpotOnly,
      Clock.systemDefaultZone());
}

/** Your original method implementation. Test this one. */
public List<DrawResultDto> getLastDrawResult(
    Optional<Long> lotteryId,
    Optional<String> name,
    Optional<String> byName,
    Optional<String> byDate,
    Optional<Boolean> jackpotOnly,
    Clock clock) {
  LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
  /* ... */
}
```

This way, in your test, you can pass in a value from [`Clock.fixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-).

Separately, you should strongly consider switching this method to parameterized queries, which [JdbcTemplate supports natively](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). You can even [support named parameters using related classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html).

Comment: Thanks for explaining in more of a detailed manner. I learned a lot from your answer. And it works. I have this question, is there a way to do it with matches method in Mockito without touching/adding anything extra to the class I'm testing? Just curious if there is a way with matches(). Like Ignore everything except the DateTime.

Comment: @Amiko I can't think of a good way to do it with `matches` without turning your expected query into an enormous and unreadable regular expression itself (though you could build the query expression using escaping tools, for instance, and concatenate in the expression you wrote). That would still be harder to read and maintain, and wouldn't test that the correct date was a part of your query. Another solution is to capture the query using ArgumentCaptor and parse it or strip out the date, with similar readability/maintainability/coverage costs. I can't recommend either solution in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are writing your tests after your code :p (otherwise you would have never run into such an issue).

What I would do is to pass the localedatetime to the function, so that you can unit test it properly :

```
public List<DrawResultDto> getLastDrawResult(LocalDateTime t, Optional<Long> lotteryId, Optional<String> name, Optional<String> byName, Optional<String> byDate, Optional<Boolean> jackpotOnly) {
    String query = QUERY_MAIN_BLOCK.replace("/*statement0*/", t.plusMinutes(buyingLock).toString()) +
    [...]
}
```

and to keep consistency with your existing code, keep the actual signature:

```
public List<DrawResultDto> getLastDrawResult(Optional<Long> lotteryId, Optional<String> name, Optional<String> byName, Optional<String> byDate, Optional<Boolean> jackpotOnly) {
    return getLastDrawResult(LocaleDateTime.now(), Optional<Long> lotteryId, Optional<String> name, Optional<String> byName, Optional<String> byDate, Optional<Boolean> jackpotOnly);
}
```

Now you can unit test properly the first method (by passing it a localedatetime built inside the test method), unit testing the second method is trivial.